# How to supervise a typed actor that has a scheduler and register itself using receptionist?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

The following is how I create a behavior:

```
Behaviors.setup(ctx => {
  ctx.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(serviceKey, ctx.self)
  Behaviors.withTimers[Request](scheduler => {
    ctx.self ! Msg1 // Not sure if this is related to this question
    scheduler.startTimerWithFixedDelay(Msg2, 1.hour)
    new MyExtensionOfAbstractBehavior(ctx,scheduler)
  })
})
```

Now I would like to add supervision. To keep it simple I want `SupervisorStrategy.resume` or `SupervisorStrategy.restart`. But I don't know how to add that supervision. I know the following code will compile. But I am not sure that is the right approach.

```
Behaviors.supervise[Request]( ... every thing in the previous code ...)
.onFailure(SupervisorStrategy.resume)
```

1. When an actor *restarts* or *resumes* its behavior, it won't get deregistered in `receptionist` (is that true?). So I should not re-register the actor every time it restarts or resumes its behavior.
2. I have a similar problem with the scheduler. I don't know if I have to make sure `Behaviors.withTimers` gets re-executed or not upon restart/ resume.

Answer (score 0):

On restart or resumption, the actor is, to the outside world, still the same actor, so I probably wouldn't wrap receptionist registration with `supervise`.  As for the timers, I think the question is whether you want to reset the timers: if you do, then wrap `withTimers` in `supervise`.